# ndiswrapper locks system when disconnecting from wifi network

Tags: wireless, networking, realtek, ndiswrapper

After some hours of fiddling with ndiswrapper I have successfully managed to connect to my wireless network with my network card which sports a Realtek RTL8190 chipset. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the Win XP 64bit driver which came with the network card. However when trying to disconnect from the wifi network or shutting down the system, the system gets locked by ndiswrapper.

System log:

```
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556371] BUG: soft lockup - CPU#6 stuck for 22s! [kworker/u16:7:189]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556382] Modules linked in: nls_utf8 isofs cfg80211 rfcomm bnep bluetooth parport_pc ppdev snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hid_microsoft hid_generic joydev xpad ff_memless rndis_host usbhid cdc_ether hid usbnet snd_hda_codec_hdmi mxm_wmi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm snd_hda_codec_realtek crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel snd_hda_intel snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep aesni_intel snd_pcm aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul snd_page_alloc glue_helper ablk_helper snd_seq_midi cryptd snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi snd_seq nvidia(POF) psmouse snd_seq_device snd_timer serio_raw snd drm lpc_ich shpchp soundcore wmi mei_me mei video mac_hid ndiswrapper(OF) lp parport ahci r8169 libahci mii
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556494] CPU: 6 PID: 189 Comm: kworker/u16:7 Tainted: PF     D   IO 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556498] Hardware name: ECT  /Z87-G43 (MS-7816), BIOS V1.3 06/06/2013
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556529] Workqueue: ntos_wq kdpc_worker [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556535] task: ffff88040427afe0 ti: ffff880404272000 task.ti: ffff880404272000
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556539] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffffa0055ae3>]  [<ffffffffa0055ae3>] KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc+0xe3/0x110 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556569] RSP: 0018:ffff880404273c90  EFLAGS: 00000202
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556572] RAX: 0000000000000001 RBX: 000000000000000c RCX: 0000000000000001
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556576] RDX: 0000000000000001 RSI: ffffc90006370000 RDI: ffff88040427afe0
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556579] RBP: ffff880404273ca0 R08: ffffc90006370000 R09: 00000000d9888000
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556582] R10: ffffffff8180ae00 R11: 0000000000007516 R12: 000000000000002e
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556586] R13: 0000000000000027 R14: 000000000000000c R15: 0000000000001268
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556590] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff88041ed80000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556594] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556598] CR2: 0000000000b101e8 CR3: 0000000001c0e000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556601] Stack:
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556604]  ffffc90006370000 ffff88003603a818 ffff880404273cc0 ffffffffa0068575
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556612]  ffffc90006370000 ffffc90006370000 ffff880404273d90 ffffc900062c3e57
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556620]  ffff88041ed8e360 0000000200000006 ffffc90006370000 ffffc900062e4c9c
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556628] Call Trace:
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556662]  [<ffffffffa0068575>] win2lin_KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc_1+0x15/0x20 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556691]  [<ffffffffa00689f8>] ? win2lin_KeReleaseSpinLock_2+0x18/0x20 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556713]  [<ffffffffa006a5ad>] ? lin2win1+0xd/0x20 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556723]  [<ffffffff8109448b>] ? task_rq_lock+0x4b/0x90
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556748]  [<ffffffffa0051ad1>] ? deserialized_irq_handler+0x21/0x40 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556778]  [<ffffffffa0067ebe>] ? win2lin_deserialized_irq_handler_4+0x1e/0x30 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556804]  [<ffffffffa0067ea0>] ? win2lin_alloc_shared_memory_async_2+0x20/0x20 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556824]  [<ffffffffa006a613>] ? lin2win4+0x13/0x20 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556852]  [<ffffffffa0053fee>] ? kdpc_worker+0xee/0x170 [ndiswrapper]
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556862]  [<ffffffff810838a2>] ? process_one_work+0x182/0x450
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556870]  [<ffffffff81084641>] ? worker_thread+0x121/0x410
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556878]  [<ffffffff81084520>] ? rescuer_thread+0x3e0/0x3e0
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556885]  [<ffffffff8108b312>] ? kthread+0xd2/0xf0
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556892]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556900]  [<ffffffff8172637c>] ? ret_from_fork+0x7c/0xb0
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556907]  [<ffffffff8108b240>] ? kthread_create_on_node+0x1d0/0x1d0
May  3 23:14:37 saturnv kernel: [  232.556910] Code: 5c 5d c3 0f 1f 44 00 00 83 03 01 bb 02 00 00 00 eb d9 48 83 fa 01 b8 01 00 00 00 77 14 f3 90 48 89 c1 49 87 0c 24 48 85 c9 74 d1 <48> 83 f9 01 76 ec 4d 89 e0 ba ea 02 00 00 48 c7 c6 9f c4 06 a0
```

Any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: Looks like a bug! Reporting the call trace at Launchpad would be a start. :-)

Comment: Well, the log contains the stack trace which ends with a call to `win2lin_KeAcquireSpinLockRaiseToDpc_1`. I've found similar stack traces in posts starting around 2009. So this isn't a new one. But I found no solution to this.